# How to make this page responsive on all screens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a very simple coupon app for Polish audience. The thing is that I don't know how to make this page responsive. On smaller screens, my page looks like this:

### Image 1: Smaller Screen

[image: Image 1]

### Image 2: Smaller Screen

[image: Image 2]

### Image 1: Larger Screen (I want to have this look on all devices)

[image: Image 3]

### Image 2: Larger Screen

[image: Image 4]

Does anyone have a clue how I can do achieve this? I want a responsive text, responsive buttons, and I want everything other to look the same on every device. How do I do this?

### Code

### Classic Coupon Screen

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ClassicCouponScreenArguments {
  final String imagePath;

  ClassicCouponScreenArguments(this.imagePath);
}

class ClassicCouponScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ClassicCouponScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'DATA WYDANIA:',
                        style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '12/11/2019',
                        style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('UNIKALNY KOD:', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0)),
                      Text('A-78-IA-6', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black, fontSize: 15.0))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Image.asset(args.imagePath),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Text.rich(
                TextSpan(
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                    text:
                        'Kupon ten upoważnia do jednokrotnego odbioru produktu gratis przy kolejnym dowolnym zakupie z oferty klasycznej. Kupon ważny jest przez 7 dni od czasu jego wygenerowania i może być zrealizowany w dowolnej restauracji Makdolan\'s w Polsce z wyłączeniem restauracji znajdujących się na terenie Portu Lotniczego im. Fryderyka Chopina w Warszawie oraz Portu Lotniczego im. Lecha Wałęsy w Gdańsku. Szczegółowy regulamin ankiety „Opinia Gości" znajduje się na stronie',
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(text: ' www.makdolan.pl ', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow)),
                      TextSpan(text: 'w sekcji', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black)),
                      TextSpan(text: ' Regulaminy', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow, decoration: TextDecoration.underline))
                    ]),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                height: 95.0,
                child: CupertinoButton(
                  color: Color(0xFFF7C443),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'DRUKUJ /',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                      ),
                      Text('ZAPISZ JAKO PDF', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0))
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Container(
                height: 95.0,
                child: CupertinoButton(
                  color: Color(0xFFF7C443),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'PRZEŚLIJ KUPON',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                      ),
                      Text('(WYSYŁKA W CIĄGU 24 GODZIN)', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0))
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Mail Coupon Screen

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:makdolan_flutter/core/makdolan.dart';

final double _sizedBox = 8.0;

class MailCouponScreenArguments {
  final String imagePath;

  MailCouponScreenArguments(this.imagePath);
}

class MailCouponScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MailCouponScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back,
                        color: CupertinoColors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.archive,
                      color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                      color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                    Icon(Icons.mail, color: CupertinoColors.black),
                    SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert,
                      color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('Voucher', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17.0)),
                    SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 2, 4, 2),
                        child: Text('Odebrane', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0)),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Icon(Icons.star_border, color: CupertinoColors.black),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        height: 45.0,
                        width: 45.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[200], shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text('M', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white)),
                        )),
                    SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('Makdolan Poland', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0)),
                            SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                            Text('Wczoraj', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.0))
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('do mnie', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.0)),
                            Icon(Icons.expand_more, color: CupertinoColors.black)
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.reply,
                      color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert,
                      color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
            Text(
              'Dzień dobry,\nPrzesyłamy kupon w podziękowaniu za wzięcie udziału w ankiecie.',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('DATA WYDANIA:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                Text(Makdolan.date(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0))
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('UNIKALNY KOD:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                SizedBox(width: _sizedBox),
                Text(Makdolan.uniqueCode(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0)),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
            Image.asset(args.imagePath),
            SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
            Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                text:
                    'Kupon ten upoważnia do jednokrotnego odbioru produktu gratis przy kolejnym dowolnym zakupie z oferty klasycznej. Kupon ważny jest przez 7 dni od czasu jego wygenerowania i może być zrealizowany w dowolnej restauracji Makdolan\'s w Polsce z wyłączeniem restauracji znajdujących się na terenie Portu Lotniczego im. Fryderyka Chopina w Warszawie oraz Portu Lotniczego im. Lecha Wałęsy w Gdańsku. Szczegółowy regulamin ankiety „Opinia Gości" znajduje się na stronie',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(text: ' www.makdolan.pl ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber, decoration: TextDecoration.underline)),
                  TextSpan(text: 'w sekcji', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                  TextSpan(text: ' Regulaminy', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber, decoration: TextDecoration.underline))
                ],
              ),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.0),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text('Dziękujemy za wzięcie udziału w badaniu!', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 13.0)),
            SizedBox(height: _sizedBox),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 110.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.reply,
                        color: CupertinoColors.black,
                      ),
                      Text('Odpowiedz', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.5))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 110.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey), borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.reply_all,
                        color: CupertinoColors.black,
                      ),
                      Text('Odpowiedz', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0)),
                      Text('wszystkim', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 110.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey), borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.forward,
                        color: CupertinoColors.black,
                      ),
                      Text('Przekaż dalej', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now There can be many ways in making the flutter app responsive.
You can use MediaQuery() parameter which is an easy way that is you can get the width and height of the device and you can use it to size your widgets.
Example :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
 body:Container() ); }
```

Now you can use

```
size.height to get device height and size.width to get device width

SizedBox(
            width: size.width * .6,
            child: BeautifulRoundedButton(
              text: "Start Reading",
              fontSize: 20,
              press: (){
                
              },
            ),
          ),
```

The Above button will be sized according to the width of the screen and will be 0.6 percent of the total width. similarly for the height

```
 SizedBox(
          height: size.height * .4,

        ),
```

References for this are : [Flutter Dev Guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive#:%7E:text=Flutter%20allows%20you%20to%20create,you%20get%20a%20BoxConstraints%20object.)
This was a simple one there are other ways and for them
Now Other really great articles I found are:
[Article 1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4324124-responsive-design-for-flutter-getting-started)  [Article 2](https://medium.com/nonstopio/let-make-responsive-app-in-flutter-e48428795476)